# XCode 4 - Build settings : default values are still bold

Tags: xcode4, default, reset, bold, build-settings

I have a project with 2 targets.
On both, there are some build settings I've changed to Yes, then back to No.
The iOS default is NO, the project is on NO, each build setting is on NO... but the setting is still bold (value changed).
As for settigns that takes strings, like Search pathes. I've put some search pathes, then removed them, and the line is still bold, even the green cell is shown to outline... no change.

How may I fix this to have a good visual ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Xcode 4 you can use the Delete key on your keyboard. In Xcode 3, there is an item in the action menu about deleting the setting from this level. I can't remember the wording exactly.

Comment: I have a Macbook without a delete key. fn-Backspace doesn't do anything and the setting item doesn't even seem to have focus when I click on it. How can I do this apart from hand-editing the project settings file?

Comment: You have a MacBook with a backspace key? It's the same key you use to delete a letter in the code editor.

Answer (score 5):

Counterintuitive as it looks, solution is to select the whole setting line and hit cmd-delete

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, especially with multi-line items, hitting delete or cmd-delete does not work. For those items I just resort to setting the first line to `$(inherited)`. This means the item is still bold, but it will otherwise have the correct value.